# GWT application: server-wide context, where to run an initial request and keep its result, so that every session access this result later on?

Tags: java, gwt, glassfish

I am developing a GWT 2.1 application, using the GlassFish app server.

All the music starts when someone requests the Web page: the UI gets built, it calls server-side methods, which query the database, and tutti quanti.

I need now a server-wide context, where to run an initial query, once and for all, and keep its result in memory, so that every session access this result later on. The code I wish to run is server-side Java code. Let's say it runs at start of the app server. Or - more subtle - when the Web home page is requested for the first time since app server start.

The initial code builds a big arborescence and takes a long time to run. The arborescence does not change and is the same for all users. So I want to construct it only once and then read it.

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on how you generate the solution.

you have 3 options atleast -

1) Database persistence- You can store the solution in a database.

2) XML - (Pre)calculate the solution, store it in an XML file, access the xml doc and use the solution

3) Generate and store the solution in a static class on the server side. Use the servlets to access this static class. (Problem, if the server goes down, you loose the solution and will have to recalculate everytime you restart the server)

If the solution is just a one time computation, I would prefer using solution 1 or 2. Some more info will be helpful though to pinpoint the right solution for you.

Comment: Thank you. I'm interested in solution 3. I want to recalculate after server restart. I really need to keep constructed Java objects and access them later. How is that feasible with a static class? With which entry point can I put the arborescence, and where?

Comment: Use a startup servlet, (via web.xml `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>`) and use static fields in that servlet. Note that if you query for data from a database in this servlet and the values change in the database it's only updated when the server is restarted, unless you do some other action. Just something to be aware of when using a construction like this.

Comment: Thank you Hilbrand. I'll search on this path.